# 2 JQuery AJAX post req with the same object

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, post, express

What I want to do, exactly, is this :

```
<form>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="follow" value="Follow">  
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('#follow').click(function(){  
      $.ajax({ 
        url: '/follow'
        , type: 'POST'
        , cache: false
        , data: { user: '<%= username %>' }
        , complete: function() {


         },

        success: function(data) {

        },

        error: function() {

           console.log('process error');

        },
   });

   $('#follow').attr('value', 'Following');  
   $('#follow').attr('id', 'unfollow'); 
 });   

 $('#unfollow').click(function(){  
      $.ajax({ 
        url: '/unfollow'
        , type: 'POST'
        , cache: false
        , data: { user: '<%= username %>' }
        , complete: function() {


         },

        success: function(data) {


        },

        error: function() {

           console.log('process error');

        },
   });

   $('#follow').attr('value', 'Follow');  
   $('#follow').attr('id', 'follow'); 
 });           

</script>
```

The first post req works perfectly, but the second req not. When I press the button, the value doesn't change and I don't receive the correspondent post req to `/unfollow`. What's the problem here?

Thanks advance!

Comment: You have an extra comma after both `error:` functions, that's invalid Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event bindings happen when the DOM is first loaded. When you change the ID's dynamically, that doesn't cause the bindings to change.  You need to delegate with `on()` for this to work.

```
$(".btn").on("click", "#follow", function() {...});
$(".btn").on("click", "#unfollow", function() {...});
```

Another option would be to *not* change the ID. Use a single handler, and check whether the value is currently `"Follow"` or `"Unfollow"`, and call the appropriate URL.

```
$("#follow").click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Follow") {
        $(this).val("Unfollow");
        var url = "/follow";
    } else {
        $(this).val("Follow");
        var url = "/unfollow";
    }
    $.ajax( {
        url: url
        , type: 'POST'
        , cache: false
        , data: { user: '<%= username %>' }
        , complete: function() {
        },

        success: function(data) {
        },
        error: function() {
           console.log('process error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but you cannot delegate in that way. you delegate from parent to child element, but not from parent to self. for your code to work `#btn` would need to become `document`

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the way delegation works is that it binds a handler to `.btn`, and the handler checks whether the target element `is("#follow")`. I don't think it has to be a strict parent-child relationship. But if it does, `".btn"` could become `"form"`.

Comment: only if all buttons are in a form :)

Comment: We don't care about __all__ buttons, just this one button. And it's in a form.

Comment: Since he's binding to a specific ID, not a class, it can be pretty specific. All that matters is the HTML surrounding that button (unless he's planning on shifting this ID all over the document, which is really poor design).

Answer (score 0):

Barmar is correct, but you also are not referencing your ID's properly.

You're looking for #follow after you've already changed it to #unfollow :)

Here's an example of what you want to do.

```
$(document).ready( function(){

   $("body").on("click", "#follow", function(){
      $(this).val("Unfollow");  
      $(this).attr("id","Unfollow"); 
   });

   $("body").on("click", "#Unfollow", function(){
      $(this).val("Follow");  
      $(this).attr("id","follow"); 
   }); 

});
```

And [here it is at Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gb9Xa/)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the id is not a good idea.

You can get the correct effect by keeping the id the same, and testing the `value` within a single click handler, like this :

```
$('#follow').on('click', function(){
    if(this.value == 'Follow') {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/follow',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: { user: '<%= username %>' },
                complete: function() {
            },
            success: function(data) {
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('process error');
            }
        });
        $(this).attr('value', 'Following'); 
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: '/unfollow',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: { user: '<%= username %>' },
            complete: function() {
            },
            success: function(data) {
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('process error');
            }
        });
       $(this).attr('value', 'Follow'); 
    }
});
```

You may be able to simplify down to one `$.ajax()` block, depending on how similar the success/error/complete functions are.

You might also like to move the statements that change #follow's value inside the success handler. Otherwise the button's value will tell a lie at least for a moment, or for longer if an ajax error occurs.